# Two Left Joins, only one is using an index

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, query-optimization

I'll show my query first, then the tables. I've tried forcing the index, but it just won't. When that part of the query is ran as a new query on its own, it uses the index and is fast, but since it won't in my full query, it's incredibly slow / never completes.

```
SELECT p.*, INET_NTOA(p.ip) AS ipStr, qs.score, db.*
FROM proxies p

LEFT JOIN ipdb db FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`iprange`)
ON db.ipStart <= p.ip AND db.ipEnd >= p.ip

LEFT JOIN ipqs qs ON qs.ip = p.ip

WHERE expiration_date < '2021-09-18'
ORDER BY expiration_date
LIMIT 500
```

'iprange' is an index on ipStart + ipEnd.
There are indexes on p.ip and expiration_date

Explain results:

---

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p | range | expirationdate | expirationdate | 4 | NULL | 2547 | Using index condition |
| 1 | SIMPLE | db | ALL | iprange | NULL | NULL | NULL | 8334413 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | qs | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | adscend_Aff.p.ip | 1 | NULL |

The query of ipdb, ran by itself, sometimes uses the index and sometimes doesn't.... When it doesn't it takes 17 seconds, when it does it takes 0.4 seconds.

```
explain SELECT * FROM ipdb db WHERE db.ipStart <= 785476891 AND db.ipEnd >= 785476891;

explain SELECT * from ipdb db where db.ipStart <= 16941057 AND db.ipEnd >= 16941057;
```

---

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | db | ALL | iprange | NULL | NULL | NULL | 8334413 | Using where |

---

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | db | range | iprange | iprange | 4 | NULL | 86 | Using index condition |

When I force the index:

---

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | db | range | iprange | iprange | 4 | NULL | 1818402 | Using index condition |

and takes 1.8 seconds.

Tried FORCE INDEX instead of FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN in the larger query, but no difference. Not sure how to address this. Tried splitting this into two steps and doing the second step within a php loop but it's still crazy slow that way

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: You have not yet given us enough information to help you. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And approximately how many rows in the table?  And how many in each sample `SELECT`.  (The values are a clue to the "why".)

Answer (score 0):

If `startIp` is at the wrong end of the table, forcing that index will force it to go through most of the table.  You can't win.

Start over on designing the table and the queries.  Here is a technique that runs O(1) instead of O(N):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges